# Only one sticky header in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a single sticky header in a `UICollectionView`.

My sticky header behavior is a bit different than the usual one you can see e.g. in `UITableView`. I have 3 headers in the collection view and **I want only one of them to be sticky** and stick to the top when the content is scrolled.

My code works pretty well. However, when I scroll down, the sticky header disappears suddenly at some point. Scrolling back makes the header appear again. What am I doing wrong?

I am attaching a implementation of my custom layout. It's a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

```
@implementation CustomFlowLayout


- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];
    CGPoint const contentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in attributes)
    {
        // Adjust the sticky header frame.
        if ([layoutAttributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader] &&
            layoutAttributes.indexPath.section == SectionWithStickyHeadeIndex)
        {
            NSInteger numberOfItemsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:SectionWithStickyHeadeIndex];
            NSIndexPath *firstObjectIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0
                                                                    inSection:SectionWithStickyHeadeIndex];
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *firstObjectAttrs;

            if (numberOfItemsInSection > 0)
            {
                firstObjectAttrs = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:firstObjectIndexPath];
            }
            else
            {
                firstObjectAttrs = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                        atIndexPath:firstObjectIndexPath];
            }

            CGPoint origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin;

            // Adjust the header origin so it sticks to the top.
            origin.y = MAX(contentOffset.y + self.collectionView.contentInset.top,
                           CGRectGetMinY(firstObjectAttrs.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame));

            layoutAttributes.zIndex = CGFLOAT_MAX;
            layoutAttributes.frame = (CGRect)
            {
                .origin = origin,
                .size = layoutAttributes.frame.size
            };

            break;
        }
    }

    return attributes;
}


- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBound
{
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but it looks like once you scrolled down far enough, the header's original position was no longer located inside the `rect` argument. This caused the header's layout attributes to not be included in the `attributes` array you iterated over in in the `for` loop, resulting in the layout position no longer being adjusted to its "sticky" position at the top of the screen.

Try adding these lines right before the `for` loop to add the sticky header's layout attributes to the `attributes` array if they are not already there:

> ```
> NSIndexPath *stickyHeaderIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:SectionWithStickyHeaderIndex];
> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
>                                                                                           atIndexPath:stickyHeaderIndexPath];
> if (![attributes containsObject:layoutAttributes])
> {
>     [attributes addObject:layoutAttributes];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in Swift 5

```
let headerIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
if let headerAttributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: headerIndexPath) {
    if !attributes.contains(headerAttributes) {
        attributes.append(headerAttributes)
    }
}
```

All thanks to @BrendanCain